# Oracle selecting one row from multiple rows based on a column value

Tags: sql, oracle, report

I am using Oracle SQL. 
Here is the example table:

```
MachineStatus
--------------
Machine        Status  date_time               station
G1          1       07/09/2014 10:11        s1
G2          1       07/09/2014 10:11        s1
G3          0       07/09/2014 10:11        s1

G1          1       07/09/2014 10:12        s1
G2          1       07/09/2014 10:12        s1
G3          0       07/09/2014 10:12        s1

G1          0       07/09/2014 10:13        s1
G2          0       07/09/2014 10:13        s1
G3          0       07/09/2014 10:13        s1
```

I want to list the status of the station on any given minute as available if any of the machines is available(if status is 1) as below.

```
Station    status             date_time
s1           1               07/09/2014 10:11
s1           1               07/09/2014 10:12
s1           0               07/09/2014 10:13
```

A report needs to be generated on a daily/weekly basis based on the availability.

How should I approach this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will give you the result from your example:

```
SELECT
    station,
    (CASE WHEN sum(status) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status,
    date_time
FROM MachineStatus
GROUP BY station, date_time
ORDER BY date_time
```

Having at least one status that is 1 means that the sum of statuses for that group and date_time must be greater than 1.

Comment: A filter should not be used. I have list the status of s1 as 1 only if any of machines is available.

Comment: Like I said: a little bit unclear what you're asking for. Is your problem solved?

Comment: Well, you provide an example table and an example expected output. I give you a query that satisfies your requirements, but you seem to disagree. So what am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, the question was indeed little unclear. I have edited the question a little bit. For a given minute, the station status is 1 if any one of the machines associated with the station has status 1. If all of them have a status 0, then the status of the station is 0.